# input type file opacity 0 not working in ie for upload?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, styles

I am uploading a file in a page. This works fine for Firefox, Chrome, Opera. But in IE it doesn't work. Because I set the style `filter:alpha(opacity=0)`.

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return sub()">
    <div id="FileUpload">
        <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" size="24" multiple="" onChange="up()" style="opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);" />
        <div id="BrowserVisible" onclick="$('#filesToUpload').click();"><input type="text" id="FileField" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How to fix it in IE?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.. do you want to invoke click on the file input, on clicking somewhere else??.

Comment: yes i invoking the click of file input on clicking the "BrowserVisible" div...

Comment: You cant do that, in Ie its a security issue, you cant trigger click on file input using js or jquery.